# WPF - DataGrid shall not handle Ctrl+A

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, command, key-bindings

In my WPF application I have a custom key binding to one of my commands:

```
<KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="A" Command="local:MainWindow.SelectAll" />
```

(What it does is it select the whole area on an image with a bounding box for later processing.)

There is also a DataGrid in the main window. The `Ctrl+A` key works well on the application until I once clicked into the DataGrid. From that point, the DataGrid handles it (but doesn't do anything since it is not a multiselect grid).

How can I achieve the the DataGrid doesn't handle `Ctrl+A`, so it will always fire my command?

Here's my DataGrid if that helps:

```
<DataGrid Name="myDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Single"
EnableRowVirtualization="True" SelectedCellsChanged="myDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged"
IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove this kind of included binding by using this:

```
<DataGrid>  
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
<KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+A" Command="ApplicationCommands.NotACommand"/>  
</DataGrid.InputBindings>  
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I rather set it to "local:MainWindow.SelectAll" by the way, so it will call that one also.